# AngularJS - How to programmatically fire validation

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom validation, for example, blacklisted. My model value and blacklisted array are the following:

```
model = "not_blacklisted_yet"
blacklisted = ["foo", "bar"]
```

I want to add `"not_blacklisted_yet"` to `blacklisted`, and to fire the validation programmatically. If I just add the element, the validation is not triggered because I have not changed the models viewValue.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT, atach plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/L2sJY9VOJ7s8lKCm88sM?p=preview

Comment: you can have a look at $scope.$watch and watch `blacklisted` to trigger the validation you are talking about

Comment: done, http://plnkr.co/edit/L2sJY9VOJ7s8lKCm88sM?p=preview

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what @Atrix1987 said in his comment. Your requirements need two entry points to trigger the said validation - one is when the form controller's `modelValue` changes and the other is when the `blacklisted` changes. The former has already been taken care of by the use of `ui-validation`, so that leaves us to deal with the latter scenario.

We want to trigger the validation whenever `blacklisted` changes, so we need to monitor it via the use of `$watch`. In your controller add the following:

```
$scope.$watch('blacklisted', function(content) {
  if (content) {
    $scope.form.model.$setValidity(
      'blacklist',
      $scope.notBlackListed($scope.form.model.$modelValue)
    );
  }
}, true);
```

Or here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBwIxqx6M2vRkoaeXPxV?p=preview)